# When using repo tool how to delete all commits but keep my changed files?

Tags: android, github, synchronization, repository

Im using the repo tool to sync android source.
I have two questions about this;

- When I change something in the source and sync later on but want to keep the changes, what is the correct way to do this? (im now doing git add ., git commit and later on merge if necessary) But this seems not to be the right way.
- Can I reset the entire repo (all git dirs) to remove all commits but still keep all my changed files? (because they are all polluted with commits now)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As Far As I know repo does this for you. Once its done with sync it rebase you chanegs on TOP of that.

Or else you can try

git pull --rebase